# Need to make sure I interpreted the question correctly (I fixed the question I need some upvotes to lay off my question ban)

Tags: python, class

Define a class for a type called CounterType. An object of this type is used to count
things, so it records a count that is a nonnegative whole number.

a. Private data member: count.

b. Include a mutator function that sets the counter to a count given as an argument.

c. Include member functions to increase the count by one and to decrease the count
by one.

d. Include a member function that returns the current count value and one that outputs
the count.

e. Include default constructor that set the count to 0.

f. Include one argument constructor that set count to given argument.

Be sure that no member function allows the value of the counter to become negative.

Embed your class definition in a test program.

An output example would be:

```
a = CounterType(10)
a.display()
a.increase()
a.display()
a.setCounter(100)
a.display
```

Will display the following:

```
Counter: 10
Counter: 11
Counter: 100
```

I have written the code but I just want to make sure that it is following what the question asked and if there could be an easier way to write this code.

```
class CounterType:
  def __init__(self, counter=0):
    self.counter = counter
  def increase(self):
    self.counter += 1
  def decrease(self):
    if self.counter == 0:
      print("Error, counter cannot be negative")
  else:
    self.counter -= 1
  def setCounter(self, x):
    if x < 0:
      print("Error, counter cannot be negative")
    else:
      self.counter = x
  def setCount0(self):
    self.counter = 0
  def display(self):
    print("Counter:", self.counter)
  def getCounter(self):
    return self.counter
```

This is a homework assignment so it would help if you could just give some tips

Comment: You didn't do this: **Be sure that no member function allows the value of the counter to become negative.**

Comment: So should I cut and copy paste the if statement to the other functions?

Comment: You didn't do step d or e

Comment: You didn't default the counter to 0 on construction. Also, I would personally rename setCounter to set, rename setCount0 to reset (or simply delete this and use set(0) instead), rename increase to increment, and rename decrease to decrement. Also don't print error messages when attempting to set negative values, raise a RangeError.

Comment: You don't need the if statement in `increase`. But all the other functions that set the counter need to check.

Comment: And if you prevent the counter ever becoming negative, you don't need to check it in `display`

Comment: Ok check the new edit

Comment: Fix the indentation.

Comment: Ok thank you guys for the help :)

Comment: Still missing: **Include a member function that returns the current count value**

Comment: Isn't that the same thing as display()?

Comment: Return != display

Comment: ah I understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot "Be sure that no member function allows the value of the counter to become negative."

The naïve way to do this is to add an `if` condition in every function. A smarter way would be to add that check the `setCounter` function and use this function from all other functions.

```
class CounterType:

  def __init__(self, counter=0): # (e, f) counter = 0: default argument value so x = CounterType() works and has a counter of 0
    self.counter = 0  # (a)
    self.setCounter(counter)

  def increase(self): # (c)
    self.setCounter(self.counter + 1)

  def decrease(self): # (c)
    self.setCounter(self.counter - 1)

  def setCounter(self, x): # (b)
    if x < 0:
      print("Error, counter cannot be negative")
    else:
      self.counter = x

  def setCount0(self): # This is not needed
    self.counter = 0
  
  def display(self): # (d)
    print("Counter:", self.counter)

  def getCounter(self): # (d)
    return self.counter
```